# Unable to push django application to bluemix

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud

I am unable to push my django application to bluemix and keeps on getting following error:

Error while running '$ `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`'.
See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed

I haven't made any major changes to the code still 2 of my apps are giving me same error while pushing the code.
I am using python version 2.7.10 and django version 1.6.5.

Edit-
Traceback-

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3ADL.jpg)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv + ['0.0.0.0:' + str(PORT)])
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in handle
           raise CommandError("Command doesn't accept any arguments")
       django.core.management.base.CommandError: Command doesn't accept any arguments
```

!     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Shouldn't you post the traceback mentioned? And please do post it as TEXT and not an image

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack overflow and dont know the rules.. I added traceback to my question.

Comment: Could you add the commands you are running plus the requirements.txt and Procfile?

Comment: command-   cf push -f manifest.yml                                           Requirements.txt -                                                                                             Django==1.6.5
pygal==1.5.0
pymongo==2.8.0
cloudant==2.0.0a1
twitter==1.14.3
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-cors-headers==1.0.0
xlwt==1.0.0
requests==2.7.0

Comment: I am not sure about procfile as its not their in my directory and I think that is internally handled by heroku as bluemix is on top of it.